# node.js unit test to check that a token is expired after the set time

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I want to be able to test that a token will expire after the defined interval when creating the token.

this is my code using json-web-token module:

```
var generateToken = function (uid, callback) {
    var token = jwt.sign({ uid: uid }, secret, {expiresInMinutes: 60});
    callback(null, token);
};
```

this is my verify function:

```
var authenticate = function (token, callback) {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decoded){
        if (err)
            callback(err);
        else
            callback(null, decoded);
    });
};
```

how can i write a test with mocha to mock(simulate) a time difference of 60 minutes so i will be able to see that the token will expire when trying to verify it.

Answer (score 6):

[Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) (`npm install sinon`) has support for manipulating the javascript's clock, via `sinon.useFakeTimers`, as described in its [Fake Timers documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock).

Here's an example which might work for you:

```
var clock;

describe('Auth token validation', function () {
    // Runs before tests:
    before(function () {
        // Stub the clock with sinon:
        clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    })
    // Runs after tests:
    after(function () {
        // Restore current clock for other tests:
        clock.restore();
    });

    // Test part of the block:
    it("should expire token after an hour", function (callback) {
        // Generate a token as you normally would:
        generateToken(uid, function (err, token) {
            // Utilize the test for generateToken as well, why not? :)
            should.not.exist(err);
            // Move clock forward by one hour + 100ms:
            clock.tick(3600100);
            // Try the authentication:
            authenticate(token, function (err, decoded) {
                // You expect no decoded value:
                should.not.exist(decoded);
                // Expect error to be other than null or undefined:
                should.exist(err);
                // Use it() callback to delay test ending before async operations are finished: 
                callback();
            });
        });
    });
    // Note any other tests (it(..) statements)
    // in this describe block will use the mocked clock.
});
```

Sinon is super-useful for tests, and will allow you to avoid introducing code changes especially for tests. If this solution doesn't work for you, I'm it's a tiny fix to correct it for your needs. :)

Comment: @lobengula3rd, if you need further documentation or help with this one, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a (good?) way to make the time go faster in JavaScript.

What you can do, however, is create two environments (for example using NODE_ENV) and a configuration file for each of them. Inside the configuration file (which could be just a JSON document) you can write the value for `expiresInMinutes`): "60" for the production environment and "1" for the test environment (if you can specify an interval in seconds, then it's even better). Then just run the mocha test in parallel, and after one minute you'll see how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Json Web Tokens and the and the jwt library (`jsonwebtoken`), you can verify the token using a future date with `clockTimestamp`:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('JWT', function () {
  let oneHourFromNow, token;
  let secretKey = 'mySecret';

  before(() => {
    oneHourFromNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60)
    token = jwt.sign({
      id: 123,
      exp: oneHourFromNow
    }, secretKey);
  });

  it('should not expire before an hour', (done) => {
    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, {clockTimestamp: oneHourFromNow - 1}, (err, decoded) => {
      expect(decoded).to.be.an('object');
      expect(decoded.id).to.be.ok;
      expect(err).to.be.null;
      done()
    });
  });

  it('should expire after an hour', (done) => {
    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, {clockTimestamp: oneHourFromNow + 1}, (err, decoded) => {
      expect(err).not.to.be.undefined;
      expect(decoded).to.be.undefined;
      done()
    });
  });
});
```